# Change list style attribute from code behind

Tags: css, asp.net

Is there a way to change list style attribute from code behind or to use Eval?
I have an asp:Reapeater, inside that repeater i have a list, so based on value i'am getting from user i want to change the list color background.

This is repeater:

```
<div class="section serviceList">
<ul>        
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <a href='<%# Eval("PageUrl") %>' target="_blank">
                <img src='<%# GetImageUrl("Picture") %>' alt="#" style="width: 36px; height: 38px; overflow: hidden;"/>
                <span><%# Eval("Title") %></span>
                <br/>
            </a>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: Yes, it's just a template not a fixed item repeated as-is (otherwise pretty useless). As you can insert specific values for each item you can also use style=" where string comes from an expression (as you do for GetImageUrl())

Comment: have a look at this OnItemDataBound: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.onitemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx.  I would also move your `ul` start and end tags into the repeaters header and footer templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that helped me

`<li style='background-color: <%# Eval("BackgroundColor.PersistedValue") %>; '>`